# Django - Code between Declaration and Render not executing

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I'm creating a simple web page with a form but the form content is not loading and after doing some digging i've discovered that any code between the function declaration request and the render is not being executed.

```
@login_required(login_url='')
def index(request):
    print('Hello World!')
    project = projectForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': project})
```

So in the above example Hello World! and creation of the project form do not execute, but the page loads, albeit without any form content.

Anyone come across this, can shed some light on what the problem may be?

**Update** Suspecting I've done something wrong with the authentication, i'll check it and update

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that I was using a render instead of a redirect at the end of my login process.

```
if user is not None:
        # A backend authenticated the credentials
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('index'). <--- this line
```

maybe this helps someone else in future